# Is there a command line argument parsing library that supports parsing java like system argument (-Dproperty=value)?

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

Basically I would like to specify a number of different argument, and ideally have a Dictionary populated.  Something along the lines of:

```
 c:\> MyApp.exe -Dproperty1=value1 -Dproperty2=value2
```

Would translate to something like:

```
 Dictionary<string,string>() { { "property1", "value1" }, { "property2", "value2" } }
```

I have looked at a number of solutions, and none of them seem to support this type of syntax.  Before I create my own, or modify someone else's, I though I would ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own parsing algorithm. Anyway, It's not that hard using `Linq`, for example:

```
args.Skip(1) // skip the program name
.Select(x => { 
                var parts = x.Split('='); 
                return new KeyValuePair<string,string>(
                            parts[0].Replace("-D",""),
                            parts[1]);
             }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key,x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Ya, that would work well if these were the only type of argument that I would need to provide.  The app will have other though, filename, logfilename, whatever.  I was hoping for a solution that allows me to create a few attribute classes, and let something else deal with the parsing, validation and help generation.

Comment: @travis you can add `.Where(x => x.StartsWith("-D"))` before the Select. that will only give you arguments that starts with -D